# POS for .NET line breaks

Tags: c#, epson, pos-for-.net

I am using "PosPrinter" .NET class to print receipts to POS Printer. Everything seems to be working fine except the line breaks. When I pass in a long string it does automatically breaks the long line into more than 1 line but it actually breaks WITHIN the word.

So, I need a way to break the word instead of breaking within the word. I appreciate your help. T

**Code**

```
m_Printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "\u001b|N华夷风起 : 华夷风起：槟城文史研习营 = When the wind of the Sinophone blows: Penang seminar 2019.\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such specification in POS for.NET(UnifiedPOS).

If that is the case, it may be a special feature of particular printer hardware or service object.

Please ask the printer vendor about the availability of such a function and ON/OFF.

If more information about the printer vendor and model is added, someone may be able to answer.

However, since there is probably no such function, you will need to read the value of the RecLineChars property and edit the content to be printed in advance by the application itself.